# Retrofit, how to parse JSON objects with variable keys

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

First I know my title is bad as I didn't come up with better, I'm opened to suggestion.

I'm using retrofit to get data from an api of this kind : `@GET("users/{userid}")`

It works fine and I'm happy with it, the problem is when I call the same api with `@POST("users/widget")` with a list of ids. I have the following answer :

```
{
  "long_hash_id": {
    "_id": "long_hash_id"
    .......
  },
  "long_hash_id": {
    "_id": "long_hash_id",
    .....
  },
  ........
}
```

the "long_hash_id" is typicaly "525558cf8ecd651095af7954"
it correspond to the id of the user attached to it.

When I didn't use retrofit, I used Gson in stream mode to get each user one by one. But I don't know how to tell retrofit.

Hope I'm clear and
Thank you in advance.

----------- Solution :

I made my interface this way :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(AppConstants.ROUTE_USER_GROUP)
Call<Map<String,User>> getUsers( @Field("ids") List<String> param, @QueryMap Map<String,String> options);
```

and I simply gave my ArrayList of ids. Thank you very much

Comment: Did you want to parse it ? or whet is the problem

Comment: yes I want to parse it with retrofit, for now I don't use retrofit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Gson` is able to deal with JSON objects with variable keys  like the one you posted. What you have to do, in this case, is to declare a `Map<String, ModelClass>`, where `ModelClass` is the content of the JSONObject you want to represent

Comment: Thank you ! I declare it to who ? I create a new Model containing juste this map ? maybe you have a link or key words for me to find it ?

Comment: post the code you are using. Your Retrofit interface declaration, and the Model class. I'll try to guide you trough that

Comment: ok I did it, "jsonObjectToUrlEncodedString" take in this case the json array and convert it to urlencoded,

Comment: for now I use generics because it's a method used for a lot of routes that works the same way

Comment: Ok, thank you very much it worked. I update my title and my question